# Lookup value in merged cell

Tags: excel, merge, vlookup, cells

I have a problem with Excel.

I have a table that has values in column A such that the values correspond to multiple values in column B. Like A contains car company in a merged cell A1:A6 and B contains 6 car names in individual cells that belong to that company.

Now I have to perform VLookup with Car Company as LookUp value and then return all the car names belonging to that company.

The problem is that when I performs VLookUp, the car name in the first cell is returned instead of all 6 cars.

Sorry that I am Unable to add any pictures of excel here, since my reputation on stackoverflow isn't enough.

Comment: You can't use VLOOKUP to do this.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens, any suggestion or alternative of doing this please?

Comment: Consider a user-defined function.

Comment: @DavidZemens any small example would be great help... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Put this in an ordinary code module in your workbook:

```
Function GetModelNames(make As String, columnRange As Range, columnOffset As Integer)
Dim r As Long
Dim mergeRange As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim ret
'Gets the first ROW within specified columnRange
r = Application.Match(make, columnRange, False)

'iterate over the mergeArea
For Each cl In columnRange(r).MergeArea
    'Concatenate a string of each cell in the offset column:
    ret = ret & IIf(ret = "", "", ", ") & cl.Offset(, columnOffset).Value

Next

'return the value to the function
GetModelNames = ret
End Function
```

Then call it like:

```
=GetModelNames("Ford", A:A, 1)
```

The arguments:

- `make`: should be the vehicle manufacturer
- `columnRange`: should be a byRef range address, e.g., "A1:A500" or "A:A", etc.
- `columnOffset`: how many columns away from the columnRange?

Comment: Cheers. If this has solved your problem, do mark the answer as "Accepted"